# I installed a docker on osx, now bundler is horrifically slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, docker

I installed docker, docker-machine and a vm a few days ago (running osx). Now when I'm working in a standard ruby on rails project with a Gemfile, bundler runs HORRIFICALLY SLOW.

For instance, before all these installations, when I had all the Gems installed locally in my Gemfile and I ran the command, `bundle install`. It took about 1-5 seconds to run tops. Now, after these installs, it takes about 5 minutes. Most notably taking 3 minutes to finish `Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/`, then another 2 minutes. If I don't have all the gems install, it takes around 15 minutes to complete `bundle install`.

I even turned off `docker-machine`, still no luck.

Any ideas on debugging this disaster?

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `http://rubygems.org/` instead of `https://rubygems.org/`

This advice can be used, but remember about security.

2) Try to use `--jobs` option

> The --jobs option (-j for short) installs gems in parallel. For
>   example, bundle install -j4 will use 4 workers. We've seen speedups of
>   40-60% on fresh bundle installs. To always install in parallel, run
>   bundle config --global jobs 4 or set BUNDLE_JOBS

There are some speed issues with old bundler versions, so if you have old version update it.